# How to speed up case_when/conditional mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tidygraph

One can notice that `case_when` do not evaluate in the formula the subset of the tibble when condition is met, but the whole tibble, an example:

```
picks = c(1:3)

a = tibble(id = c(1:4),
           k = NA)

a %>% mutate(
  k = case_when(id %in% picks~runif(length(picks)))
)
```

This is clear in the error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `k`. i `k = case_when(id %in% picks ~ runif(length(picks)))`. x `id %in% picks ~ runif(length(picks))` must be length 4 or one, not 3.
```

an alternative would be to `rowwise()` or `group_by(id)` but that would still be highly inefficient. I would probably still route for `rowwise()`, but since I have to perform operations only on 1% of the tibble, I just want a mutate within that 1%, anything else untouched. Any suggestion to make R perform the minimal number of evaluations?

I tought about combination of `filter` and `join`, but, for example, that would not work for a `tidygraph` object, because through filtering the `nodes`, one would filtering out `edges` too, so `local_members` would not work anymore properly.

EDIT:

Also, in my experience, it seems that `base::ifelse` is faster than `dplyr::case_when`; is that expected?

Comment: The error is there are 4 rows of IDs and yet only 3 values from runif. I think you want `length(nrow(a))` and not `length(picks)`

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::if_else` is faster than `base::ifelse`. You also need `T ~ NA_real_` in the `case_when` together with `n()`:

```r
picks = c(1:3)

a = tibble(id = c(1:4),
           k = NA)

a %>% mutate(
    k = case_when(
        id %in% picks~runif(n()),
        T ~ NA_real_
    )
)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id       k
  <int>   <dbl>
1     1  0.0757
2     2  0.708 
3     3  0.255 
4     4 NA  
# Would be faster with if_else:
a %>% mutate(
    k = if_else(id %in% picks,
        runif(n()),
        NA_real_
    )
)
```